# ACF Repeater display row number

Tags: count, repeater, rows, advanced-custom-fields

Looking to display the individual number of each repeater row. So for example, the first row will display "1" and the second row will display "2".

I found this from Elliot,

```
<?php echo count( get_field('repeater_field') );?>
```

which counts how many rows there are in total. But I need the individual number next to each.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any code examples of how you're trying to utilize this? I'd suggest creating a variable (equal to zero) above your while loop, and inside the loop, add 1 to that variable. This would get you a count of which item you're looping through, but if you used anything to randomize your order, that wouldn't show if it was the 3rd item in the admin, just the 3rd item on-screen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at Elliot's answer here:

http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/getting-instance-and-sort-of-id-of-repeater-field/

You would want to set up a counter variable ( $i ) and then add 1 to $i inside the loop.

```
<?php if( have_rows('repeater_field') ): $i = 0; ?>
    <div class="repeater_loop">
    <?php while( have_rows('repeater_field') ): the_row(); $i++; ?>
        <p>This is row number <?php echo $i; ?>.</p>
        <!-- call your sub_fields as needed -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This would output a div with a paragraph tag that displays your row number.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

There is [get_row_index()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_row_index/) already available to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if( have_rows('tabel_produse_profit') ): $i = 0; ?>

<table width="100%" class="tab">
  <tr>
    <td>Nr.</td>
    <td>Imagine</td>
    <td>Nume</td>
    <td>Evaluare</td>
    <td>Verificati pretul</td>
  </tr>

    <?php while( have_rows('tabel_produse_profit') ): the_row(); $i++;
        // vars
        $image = get_sub_field('tabel_imagine_produs');
        $link = get_sub_field('tabel_link_profit');
        $titlu = get_sub_field('tabel_titlu_profit');
        $evaluare = get_sub_field('tabel_evaluare');
        $count = count(get_field('tabel_produse_profit'));
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="row1">
            <?php echo $i; ?>
                <?php if( $count ): ?>
                    <div class="rowc"> din <?php echo $count; ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
           <td class="row2">
                <?php if( $image ): ?>
                    <img class="imag" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" />
                <?php endif; ?>
           </td>
           <td class="row3">
                <?php if( $titlu ): ?>
                    <h2><?php echo $titlu; ?></h2>
                <?php endif; ?>
           </td>
           <td class="row4">
                <?php if( $evaluare ): ?>
                    <div class="eva"><?php echo $evaluare; ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
           </td>
           <td class="row5">
                <?php if( $link ): ?>
                    <a class="ver" href="<?php echo $link; ?>">VERIFICAȚI PREȚUL</a>
                    <div class="mag">pe emag.ro</div>
                <?php endif; ?>
           </td>
            <?php echo $content; ?>
        </tr>
      <?php endwhile; ?>  
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>
```